# Firebase URL Format

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I am adopting firebase in my unity game. Image is uploaded then an URL is got by `GetDownloadUrlAsync()`.

The format of URL is something like this:

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/""ProjectName"".appspot.com/o/""imageName""?alt=media&token=""token Generated by Firebase""

Does anyone know if this is the standard format of this URL?

I am now going to extract the token number out for further processing. My idea is to split the above string by "=".

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to depend on anything embedded in that URL.  The intended use case is to simply provide an endpoint that fetches the file you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think the URL format has changed since the initial release of Firebase Storage in May 2016, it is strictly speaking not a public API. To prevent problems in the future, you should treat the URL as an opaque string.

Out of curiosity: what are you trying to accomplish with the parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adopting the URL inside unity, i want unity passes the info to another website by html GET. The website then knows the image location and show it. As a result, i can add other functions on the web page such as "share photo" button in social media.

Don't know if there is better way to achieve it :)